# Convert cURL command to python using requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, mozilla-deepspeech

I am using deepspeech and deespeech-server. I am able to send the cURL command:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @what_time_is_it.wav http://localhost:8080/stt
```

This gives me the correct speech to text translation "what time is it".

I am now trying to achieve the same result with a python script. My code is:

```py
import requests

data = {'data-binary': '@what_time_is_it.wav'}
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/stt", data=data)
print(response.content)
print(response.text)
```

I get the following output:

```py
b'Speech to text error'
```

And on my server I get:

```
STT error: File format b'data'... not understood.
```

Does anyone have ideas for how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import requests

filepath = '/path/to/what_time_is_it.wav'
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/stt", data=open(filepath).read())
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to edit the requests.post line to:
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/stt", data=open(filepath, 'rb').read())